# mysql query - not scaling well, slow with 15k records

Tags: php, mysql, query-performance, database-indexes

I have a large SQL query (mysql) used to populate a table of records in a CRM system.

This has been working well and quite fast with around 4000 records. Now reaching 15,500 it's running painfully slow. Taking around 70 seconds to return data.

I have tried adding some indexes, but with limited success. Any suggestions?

The query is:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    s.*,
    ca2.address_postcode,
    ca2.resident_status
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            a.id,
            c.name_first,
            c.name_last,
            a.created as app_created,
            a.edited,
            a.comments as custcomment,
            c.name_company,
            a.loan_amount,
            a.product_type,
            ap.packager as placed_with,
            a.introducer_id,
            a.status,
            c.contact_number,
            c.email,
            a.database,
            bd.legal_structure,
            (
                SELECT
                    ca1.id
                FROM
                    cl_customer_address AS ca1
                WHERE
                    ca1.customer_id = a.customer_id AND
                    ca1.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
                ORDER BY
                    ca1.created DESC
                LIMIT
                    1
            ) AS address_id
        FROM
            cl_application AS a
        LEFT JOIN
            cl_application_business_details as bd on bd.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN
            cl_customer AS c ON c.id = a.customer_id AND c.deleted = c.deleted
        LEFT JOIN
            cl_application_packager AS ap ON ap.application_id = a.id AND ap.status != "Declined" AND ap.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        WHERE
            (a.deleted = "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
        GROUP BY
            a.id
    ) AS s
LEFT JOIN
    cl_customer_address AS ca2 ON ca2.id = s.address_id AND ca2.deleted = ca2.deleted
WHERE
    (ca2.deleted = ca2.deleted OR ca2.deleted IS NULL)
ORDER BY
    app_created DESC
LIMIT
    0, 100;

Time: 70.382
Rows: 100
```

The table descriptions are:

```
CREATE TABLE cl_application (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  product_type tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  introducer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  loan_amount double NOT NULL,
  loan_purpose tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  comments text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  security_value double NOT NULL,
  property_address_1 tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  property_address_2 tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  property_town_city tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  property_postcode varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  property_country tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  application_source tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('WK - Working Lead','APP - Application Taken','ISS - Pack Issued','HOT - Head Of Terms Sent','APU - Application underway','OFI - Offer Issued','DIP - Deal in Progress','DUS - Declined Unsecured/Trying Secured','DUG - Declined Unsecured/Trying Guarantor','COM - Completed Awaiting Payment','PAC - Paid and Completed','TD - Turned Down','DUP - Duplicate application') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'WK - Working Lead',
  multi_stage_status text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  owner_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  token tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  cache_keyword text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  old_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  placed_with tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  submitted datetime NOT NULL,
  `database` enum('LV','TD','CD','UL') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'LV',
  snoozed datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  created datetime NOT NULL,
  edited datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FULLTEXT KEY cache_keyword (cache_keyword)
) ;

CREATE TABLE cl_application_packager (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  application_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  packager tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  packager_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  amount double DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('In Progress','Declined','Accepted','Completed') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'In Progress',
  commision double DEFAULT NULL,
  created datetime NOT NULL,
  edited datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY application_id (deleted)
) ;

CREATE TABLE cl_application_business_details (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  company_number tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  legal_structure enum('Ltd','LLP','Partnership','Sole Trader') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  incorporated date DEFAULT NULL,
  created datetime NOT NULL,
  edited datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE cl_customer (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title enum('Mr','Mrs','Ms','Miss') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  name_first tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  name_last tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  dob date NOT NULL,
  marital_status tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  name_company tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  email tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  alt_email tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  contact_number tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  home_phone_number tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  work_phone_number tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created datetime NOT NULL,
  edited datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE cl_customer_address (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  application_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  house_name tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  house_number tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  address_line_1 tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  address_line_2 tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  address_town tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  address_postcode tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  moved_in date NOT NULL,
  vacated date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  ptcabs tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  resident_status tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created datetime NOT NULL,
  edited datetime NOT NULL,
  deleted datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY customer_id (customer_id,deleted)
) ;


mysql> describe cl_application
    -> ;
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id                 | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| customer_id        | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| product_type       | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| introducer_id      | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| loan_amount        | double                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| loan_purpose       | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| comments           | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| security_value     | double                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| property_address_1 | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| property_address_2 | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| property_town_city | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| property_postcode  | varchar(8)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| property_country   | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| application_source | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| status             | enum('WK - Working Lead','APP - Application Taken','ISS - Pack Issued','HOT - Head Of Terms Sent','APU - Application underway','OFI - Offer Issued','DIP - Deal in Progress','DUS - Declined Unsecured/Trying Secured','DUG - Declined Unsecured/Trying Guarantor','COM - Completed Awaiting Payment','PAC - Paid and Completed','TD - Turned Down','DUP - Duplicate application') | NO   |     | WK - Working Lead   |                |
| multi_stage_status | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| owner_id           | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| token              | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| cache_keyword      | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| old_id             | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| placed_with        | tinytext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| submitted          | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| database           | enum('LV','TD','CD','UL')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | LV                  |                |
| snoozed            | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| created            | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| edited             | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| deleted            | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--

```
mysql> describe cl_application_business_details;
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type                                          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)                                       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| company_number  | tinytext                                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| legal_structure | enum('Ltd','LLP','Partnership','Sole Trader') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| incorporated    | date                                          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created         | datetime                                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| edited          | datetime                                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted         | datetime                                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-----------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--

```
mysql> describe cl_customer;                    
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title             | enum('Mr','Mrs','Ms','Miss') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_first        | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_last         | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dob               | date                         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| marital_status    | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name_company      | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email             | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| alt_email         | tinytext                     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| contact_number    | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| home_phone_number | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| work_phone_number | tinytext                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created           | datetime                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| edited            | datetime                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted           | datetime                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

--

```
mysql> describe cl_application_packager;
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                                                  | Null | Key | Default     | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)                                               | NO   | PRI | NULL        | auto_increment |
| application_id | int(11)                                               | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
| packager       | tinytext                                              | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| packager_id    | int(11)                                               | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| amount         | double                                                | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| status         | enum('In Progress','Declined','Accepted','Completed') | YES  |     | In Progress |                |
| commision      | double                                                | YES  |     | NULL        |                |
| created        | datetime                                              | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
| edited         | datetime                                              | NO   |     | NULL        |                |
| deleted        | datetime                                              | NO   | MUL | NULL        |                |
+----------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe cl_customer_address;
+------------------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| customer_id      | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL       |                |
| application_id   | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| house_name       | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| house_number     | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| address_line_1   | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| address_line_2   | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| address_town     | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| address_postcode | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| moved_in         | date     | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| vacated          | date     | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 |                |
| ptcabs           | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| resident_status  | tinytext | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| created          | datetime | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| edited           | datetime | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
| deleted          | datetime | NO   |     | NULL       |                |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Explain Output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL                 178913936   Using filesort
1   PRIMARY ca2 eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   s.address_id    1   Using where
2   DERIVED a   ALL PRIMARY, cache_keyword              14494   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED bd  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   s-choiceloans.a.id  1    
2   DERIVED c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   s-choiceloans.a.customer_id 1   Using where
2   DERIVED ap  ALL                 12344   Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  ca1 ref customer_id customer_id 9   func,const  1   Using where; Using filesort
```

---

After changing the query based on the answer's follow up:

https://jsbin.com/bonarucisi/2/edit?html,output

Comment: create table statements, data, and an explain output are best for future questions. Or a fiddle + explain

Comment: Good point added the create table statements now.

Comment: Never use `*` in `SELECT` Statements.

Comment: a fiddle for whomever want her http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7509a7

Comment: You have kinda many subselects and joins combined. Maybe you can replace some heavy subselects or joins by actually placing the data in the main table? This is redundancy I know. Sometimes (when you need that data nearly every time you select the "main" table) that makes sense. Set foreign key constrains and triggers accordingly to avoid old data in "parent" tables. A good example might be `ca1`.

Comment: could you document the 5 to 10 rows or so that come out of running explain before your query? [a reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Comment: @Hafenkranich: In this case the `s.*` references an inline view, in the statement itself. As long as the inline view is returning just the expressions OP needs returned, there isn't anything nefarious about using s.* in this context.

Comment: btw are you running found_rows on this thing afterwards? [Percona](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/)

Comment: @Percona - Drew - yes running found_rows afterwards for the pagination functions. 

I've added the 'Explain' output to the original post.

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I would avoid the subselect and consider refactoring it as another joined table. Subselects are not terribly efficient.

Comment: `WHERE  (ca2.deleted = ca2.deleted OR ca2.deleted IS NULL)` seems useless.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM?  Or InnoDB?  What is the size of the associated cache?  How much RAM do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest suspect is the inline view (or derived table, in the MySQL venacular.) MySQL is going to materialize the derived table, and then the outer query will run against that.

The other suspect is the correlated subquery in the SELECT list. That's going to be executed for every row returned by the outer query.

Also, the `ORDER BY app_created` is going to require a `Using filesort` operation (unless you're running a more recent version of MySQL that might build an index on the derived table.)

There's some odd predicates, e.g. `c.deleted = c.deleted`

That's going to be true for every row that has a non-NULL value in the `deleted` column. That's equivalent to `c.deleted IS NOT NULL`.

And for this:  `ca2.deleted = ca2.deleted OR ca2.deleted IS NULL`, that's always going to be true.

Neither of those should have much impact on performance however.

---

Run EXPLAIN to see the execution plan.

Absent that, here's a first cut at some recommendations:

Add a covering index on `c1_application_packager`

```
  CREATE INDEX c1_application_packager_IX2 ON c1_application_packager 
    (application_id, deleted, status, packager)
  ;
```

Add a covering index on `cl_customer_address`

```
  CREATE INDEX c1_customer_address_IX2 ON c1_customer_address
    (customer_id, deleted, created, id, address_postcode, resident_status)
  ;
```

And re-write the query to eliminate the derived table. Replace the join to ca2 with the same correlated subquery you used to return the `id` from c1_customer_address...

```
   SELECT a.id
        , c.name_first
        , c.name_last
        , a.created           AS app_created
        , a.edited
        , a.comments          AS custcomment
        , c.name_company
        , a.loan_amount
        , a.product_type
        , ap.packager         AS placed_with
        , a.introducer_id
        , a.status
        , c.contact_number
        , c.email
        , a.database
        , bd.legal_structure
        , ( SELECT ca1.id
              FROM cl_customer_address ca1
             WHERE ca1.customer_id = a.customer_id
               AND ca1.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
             ORDER BY ca1.customer_id, ca1.deleted, ca1.created DESC
             LIMIT 1
          ) AS address_id
        , ( SELECT ca2.address_postcode
              FROM cl_customer_address ca2
             WHERE ca2.customer_id = a.customer_id
               AND ca2.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
             ORDER BY ca2.customer_id, ca2.deleted, ca2.created DESC
             LIMIT 1
          ) AS address_postcode
        , ( SELECT ca3.resident_status
              FROM cl_customer_address ca3
             WHERE ca3.customer_id = a.customer_id
               AND ca3.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
             ORDER BY ca3.customer_id, ca3.deleted, ca3.created DESC
             LIMIT 1
          ) AS resident_status
   FROM cl_application a
   LEFT
   JOIN cl_application_business_details bd
     ON bd.id = a.id
   LEFT
   JOIN cl_customer c
     ON c.id = a.customer_id
    AND c.deleted IS NOT NULL
   LEFT
   JOIN cl_application_packager ap
     ON ap.application_id = a.id
    AND ap.status != 'Declined'
    AND ap.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  WHERE a.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY a.created, a.id
  ORDER BY a.created, a.id
```

Those correlated subqueries in the SELECT list are going to be executed for every row returned by the query, so that's going to be expensive.

Now we want to see if we can get an index on `c1_application` table that will help us avoid a `Using filesort` operation (to satisfy the ORDER BY and the GROUP BY clauses.)

```
  CREATE INDEX c1_application_IX2 ON c1_application
    (deleted, created, id)
  ;
```

The query relies on a MySQL-specific extension to GROUP BY behavior, not throwing an error due to non-aggregates in the SELECT list which don't appear in the GROUP BY. If there is more than one "matching" row from `c1_customer` or `c1_application_packager`, which of the rows is returned out of the GROUP BY operation is indeterminate.

No guarantee that these changes will have a positive impact on performance. (Performance could be a whole lot worse.)

Again, run EXPLAIN to see the execution plan, and adjust from there.

The next big hump is those correlated subqueries. For a shot at decent performance, it's imperative that a suitable index is available. (A proposal for a suitable covering index already specified above.)

The next cut would be eliminate the correlated subqueries from the SELECT list, If the `id` column from `c1_customer_address` was being returned as a means to get the `address_postcode` and `resident_status`, that first correlated subquery could be eliminated.

**FOLLOWUP**

Removing the correlated subqueries... adding an inline view `lc` to get the latest created date from c1_customer_address (for each customer_id), and another join to c1_customer_address to retrieve the rows with that latest created date (for each customer).

The `lc` inline view introduces a "derived table", which can be expensive for large sets, but this may be faster than using correlated subqueries.

```
  SELECT a.id
       , c.name_first
       , c.name_last
       , a.created             AS app_created
       , a.edited
       , a.comments            AS custcomment
       , c.name_company
       , a.loan_amount
       , a.product_type
       , ap.packager           AS placed_with
       , a.introducer_id
       , a.status
       , c.contact_number
       , c.email
       , a.database
       , bd.legal_structure
       , ca.id                 AS address_id
       , ca.address_postcode
       , ca.resident_status 
  FROM cl_application a
  LEFT
  JOIN cl_application_business_details bd
    ON bd.id = a.id
  LEFT
  JOIN cl_customer c
    ON c.id = a.customer_id
   AND c.deleted IS NOT NULL
  LEFT
  JOIN cl_application_packager ap
    ON ap.application_id = a.id
   AND ap.status != 'Declined'
   AND ap.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT ca1.customer_id
              , MAX(ca1.created) AS latest_created
           FROM cl_customer_address ca1
          WHERE ca1.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
          GROUP BY ca1.customer_id
       ) lc
    ON lc.customer_id = a.customer_id
  LEFT
  JOIN cl_customer_address ca
    ON ca.customer_id = lc.customer_id
   AND ca.created     = lc.latest_created
   AND ca.deleted     = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
 WHERE a.deleted = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
 GROUP BY a.created, a.id
 ORDER BY a.created, a.id
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response & suggestions.

Doing the above has the query time down to 0.78s - still a bit slower than I'd like but I'll experiment today with further tweaks and indexes.

Comment: I'd be interested in examining the EXPLAIN output from the revised query. We'd like to see if MySQL avoiding a "Using filesort" operation, and using an index to satisfy the GROUP BY/ORDER BY operation. I suspect that the correlated subqueries in the SELECT list are the biggest performance bottleneck.

Comment: I added a FOLLOWUP, removing the correlated subqueries, and using an inline view to get the "lateste" `created` for each `customer_id` (from `c1_customer_address`), and another join to the same table to get the rows (for that `customer_id` and latest `created`.) If there are two or more rows for a given `customer_id` with the same latest `created` date,  all of those rows will be returned. But the GROUP BY operation will reduce that to one row. (Which of those rows is returned is indeterminate.)

Comment: Another performance issue may be the datatypes of the columns. Specifically, the use of "text" datatype. For example, I wouldn't expect `address_postcode` to ever be over 12 characters. Even if it could be 80 characters, you would probably be better off with VARCHAR(80) as a datatype. Similarly with `resident status`. How many characters will that ever be? It is true that with large VARCHAR, you can run up against restrictions on the maximum length of a row. I'd reserve the usage of "text" datatypes for when I really want or need out-of-row storage.

Comment: Thank you for coming back on this - I tried your suggested follow up SQL and it's a little bit faster - I've updated the original post with a link to the explain output for the amended query.